# Getting null object reference when using getactivity() or getcontext() from fragment to adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm tried to use tab layout in my fragment, and its require to pass the context to adapter from my fragment,, I've tried using `getactivity()` , `rootView.getcontext()`, `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` to replace the `this` originated from

```
final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());  
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

from this
[https://www.javatpoint.com/android-tablayout#:~:text=Tabs%20are%20created%20using%20newTab,method%20addTab(Tab)%20method](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-tablayout#:%7E:text=Tabs%20are%20created%20using%20newTab,method%20addTab(Tab)%20method).

but still getting error null object reference :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
>
> at com.example.pesanpalgading20.MenuFragment.onCreateView(MenuFragment.java:81)

Here is my
`Menu Fragment :`

```
package com.example.pesanpalgading20;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link MenuFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Context context;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public MenuFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MenuFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MenuFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutView);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.containerViewPager);

        context = container.getContext();

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Makanan"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Minuman"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Jajanan"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),getFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return viewRoot;
    }
}
```

and this is the `MyAdapter :`

```
package com.example.pesanpalgading20;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.pesanpalgading20.ViewMenuHome.JajananMenuFragment;
import com.example.pesanpalgading20.ViewMenuHome.MakananMenuFragment;
import com.example.pesanpalgading20.ViewMenuHome.MinumanMenuFragment;

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context myContext;
    int totalTabs;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, FragmentManager fm, int totalTabs){
        super(fm);
        myContext = context;
        this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
    }

    //fragment per tabs

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                MakananMenuFragment makananMenuFragment = new MakananMenuFragment();
                return makananMenuFragment;
            case 1:
                MinumanMenuFragment minumanMenuFragment = new MinumanMenuFragment();
                return minumanMenuFragment;
            case 2:
                JajananMenuFragment jajananMenuFragment = new JajananMenuFragment();
                return jajananMenuFragment;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    //counts total number of tabs
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return totalTabs;
    }
}
```

and here is the  `fragment_menu.xml :`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MenuFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="455dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayoutView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"/>

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Menu" />
</FrameLayout>
```

How do I replace `this` to use context from my fragment to myAdapter properly ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your `MenuFragment` layout file? Update the question with `fragment_menu` file

Comment: ah yes, done edited in main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `containerViewPager` is not a part of your layout `fragment_menu`.

So your assignment

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.containerViewPager);
```

makes `viewPager` null.

That results in

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

So you need to give you viewpager a proper id like:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/containerViewPager"
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="455dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayoutView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"/>
```

Comment: ah yes , I'm totally forgot with the id ,,,  thanksss its work

Answer (score 1):

in your xml layout, `ViewPager` has the same @id as the `TabLayout`.
give ViewPager its id `containerViewPager` as:

```
   <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/containerViewPager"
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="455dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayoutView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"/>
```

Comment: **app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf** is not its' id.

Answer (score 1):

I think, The problem is in the xml>You haven't given any id to viewPager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1db995"/>


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```